# I have seen a lot of people use I in their code and I am not sure how nor when to use it. If anyone can please explain it, that would be appreciated

Tags: processing, p5.js

I just started using processing, and coding in general so I have no idea what anything stands for. However, I always see people using "i" in their codes, I don't really know what it stands for, so please how and when can I use "i"?

I tried searching for it online, yet I haven't found anything really helpful.

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)

Answer (score 1):

Very elementary, it is a `variable` that can hold a value.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

above line is for loop that has three parts

`initialization`, `condition`, `incrementation`

so "i" is a variable that is initialized to zero and will run upto i = 9 and fails on 10.

after every execution of the loop body, i increments with 1 .. so it will be 0,1,2,....9 and then loop ends

> you can take any variable name, i is not mandatory, it is a shorthand of `index` so people use it. Let say you take `xyz` as variable name then, for (let xyz=0; xyz <10; xyz++) {
>       // code statements
>   }